# Two sets of CSS Tabs on one page?

Tags: html, css, tabs

I am wanting to use tabs to replace a table of a website I am working on. The problem is there will be too much info in one tab set (the tabs start stacking and it looks a bit tacky). So I thought I would break them down into multiple sets of tabs.

I used this code: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-tabbed-pages.html

Modified it just a bit but my problem is I can't get the two sets of tabs to work independently. The second one either mimics what the user clicks on the first set of tabs or doesn't work at all. Is it possible to do this? Or did I mess the code up somewhere? I just copied the same code and changed everything to unique properties. Can you help?

Here is the CSS:

```
}
.hiddenTarget {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
}
.tabbedPages {
    position:relative;
    margin:50px 0;
}
ul.tabs {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}
ul.tabs li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:2px;
}
ul.tabs li a {
    display:block;
    font:normal 12px/30px arial, sans-serif;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    background:#69c;
    padding:0 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0, rgba(255, 255,                      255, 0.7)), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)), color-stop(0.5, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)));
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
background-image:linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
}
.tabcontent {
    float:left;
    width:700px;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:0 5px 5px 5px;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    display:none;
    clear:left;
    top:-1px;
    box-shadow:0 15px 10px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.tabcontent p {
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    margin:0;
    font:normal 12px/20px arial, sans-serif;
    color:#333;
}
.tabcontent h4 {
    padding:0 0 10px 0;
    margin:0;
    font:bold 14px/25px arial, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
}
.tabcontent img {
    border:1px solid #444;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;
    box-shadow:0 15px 10px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

/* change the tab to selected style */
ul.tabs li a.default, #tab1:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.default, #tab2:target ~         .tabbedPages .tabs li a.tab2, #tab3:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.tab3, #tab4:target ~  .tabbedPages .tabs li a.tab4, #tab5:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.tab5, #tab6:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.tab6, #tab7:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.tab7, #tab8:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.tab8, #tab9:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.tab9, #tab10:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.tab10 {
background-color:#fff;
border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
color:#000;
}

/* show the tab content */
div.default, #tab1:target ~ .tabbedPages div.default, #tab2:target ~ .tabbedPages         div#view2, #tab3:target ~ .tabbedPages div#view3, #tab4:target ~ .tabbedPages div#view4, #tab5:target ~ .tabbedPages div#view5, #tab6:target ~ .tabbedPages div#view6, #tab7:target     ~ .tabbedPages div#view7, #tab8:target ~ .tabbedPages div#view8, #tab8:target ~ .tabbedPages div#view9, #tab2:target ~ .tabbedPages div#view10 {
display:block;
}

/* reset the unclicked tabs to default */
#tab2:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.default, #tab3:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li         a.default, #tab4:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.default, #tab5:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.default, #tab6:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.default, #tab7:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.default, #tab8:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.default,, #tab9:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.default, #tab10:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.default {
background-color:#69c;
border:1px solid #888;
color:#fff;
}

/* hide the default tab when selecting other tabs*/
#tab2:target ~ .tabbedPages div.default, #tab3:target ~ .tabbedPages div.default,  #tab4:target ~ .tabbedPages div.default, #tab5:target ~ .tabbedPages div.default, #tab6:target ~ .tabbedPages div.default, #tab7:target ~ .tabbedPages  div.default,#tab8:target ~ .tabbedPages div.default, #tab9:target ~ .tabbedPages div.default, #tab10:target ~ .tabbedPages div.default {
display:none;
}
.clear {
    clear:left;
}
```

And Here is the HTML:

```
<b id="tab1" class="hiddenTarget"></b>
<b id="tab2" class="hiddenTarget"></b>
<b id="tab3" class="hiddenTarget"></b>
<b id="tab4" class="hiddenTarget"></b>
<b id="tab5" class="hiddenTarget"></b>
<div class="tabbedPages">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1" class="default tab1 tabpages">Tab One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" class="tab2 tabpages">Tab Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3" class="tab3 tabpages">Tab Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4" class="tab4 tabpages">Tab Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5" class="tab5 tabpages">Tab Five</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="view1" class="tabcontent default">
        <h4>Tab 'persist'</h4>
        <p>The most recently clicked tab will be remembered and stay open even if you     click elsewhere on the page or if the page is reloaded.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view2" class="tabcontent">
        <h4>Multiple Tabs</h4>
        <p>You can have multiple tabs on the same page, with only one copy of the CSS     (javascript is not required).</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view3" class="tabcontent">
        <h4>Tab Action from elsewhere on the same page.</h4>
        <p>You can also open a tab using links elsewhere on the same page.</p>
        <p>If you click this <a href="#tab1" class="tabpages">LINK</a> you will open 'Tab One' content, and if you click the link beneath this Tab Content you will open 'Tab #2' content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view4" class="tabcontent">
        <h4>Opened by a link from another page</h4>
        <p>Link from another page can select a tab on the target page when loaded.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view5" class="tabcontent">
        <h4>No restrictions on tab content</h4>
        <img src="pollensa.jpg" alt=" Polenca - Mallorca" />
        <p>Port de Pollença (Catalan pronunciation: [ˈpɔrd də poˈʎɛnsə]) (Puerto Pollensa in Castilian Spanish) is a small town in north-eastern Mallorca, Spain, situated on the Bay of Pollença. It is located about six kilometres east of the inland town of Pollença and two kilometres southeast of Cala Sant Vicenç.</p>
        <p>From <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_de_Pollen%C3%A7a">Wikipedia</a>, the free encyclopedia.</p>
        <br />
        <p>Photograph &copy stu nicholls</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<b id="tab6" class="hiddenTarget"></b>
<b id="tab7" class="hiddenTarget"></b>
<b id="tab8" class="hiddenTarget"></b>
<b id="tab9" class="hiddenTarget"></b>
<b id="tab10" class="hiddenTarget"></b>
<div class="tabbedPages">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab6" class="default tab6 tabpages">Tab One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab7" class="tab7 tabpages">Tab #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab8" class="tab8 tabpages">Tab No.3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab9" class="tab9 tabpages">The Fourth Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab10" class="tab10 tabpages">Any Content</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="view6" class="tabcontent default">
        <h4>Tab 'persist'</h4>
        <p>The most recently clicked tab will be remembered and stay open even if you click elsewhere on the page or if the page is reloaded.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view7" class="tabcontent">
        <h4>Multiple Tabs</h4>
        <p>You can have multiple tabs on the same page, with only one copy of the CSS (javascript is not required).</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view8" class="tabcontent">
        <h4>Tab Action from elsewhere on the same page.</h4>
        <p>You can also open a tab using links elsewhere on the same page.</p>
        <p>If you click this <a href="#tab1" class="tabpages">LINK</a> you will open 'Tab One' content, and if you click the link beneath this Tab Content you will open 'Tab #2' content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view9" class="tabcontent">
        <h4>Opened by a link from another page</h4>
        <p>Link from another page can select a tab on the target page when loaded.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view10" class="tabcontent">
        <h4>No restrict ions on tab content</h4>
        <img src="pollensa.jpg" alt=" Polenca - Mallorca" />
        <p>Port de Pollença (Catalan pronunciation: [ˈpɔrd də poˈʎɛnsə]) (Puerto Pollensa in Castilian Spanish) is a small town in north-eastern Mallorca, Spain, situated on the Bay of Pollença. It is located about six kilometres east of the inland town of Pollença and two kilometres southeast of Cala Sant Vicenç.</p>
        <p>From <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_de_Pollen%C3%A7a">Wikipedia</a>, the free encyclopedia.</p>
        <br />
        <p>Photograph &copy stu nicholls</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can view the code in action here (scroll down a bit): crystalvaults.com/medicine-wheel-guide

Thank you!

**Edited to add:** I am currently messing about with the code to see if I can fix it, so it may look a little funky if you visit.

Comment: I found the answer by trial and error. I don't know if this is the best way by any means but it works for me. I ended up separating the css. So I copy and pasted the css above again once below and changed everything by adding Two. Then each CSS block held its own information about the tabs. This seemed to make them completely independent of each other now! :) I can't answer my own question yet but I will tomorrow just in case anyone else runs into this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that worked for me. Tabs with CSS and HTML. This is probably not the cleanest code, but it will work if you are having the same issue.

**CSS:**

```
.hiddenTarget {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
}
.tabbedPages {
    position:relative;
    margin:50px 0;
    display:block;
}
ul.tabs {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}
ul.tabs li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:2px;
}
ul.tabs li a {
    display:block;
    font:normal 12px/30px arial, sans-serif;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    background:#69c;
    padding:0 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)), color-stop(0.5, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)));
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
    background-image:linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
}
.tabcontent {
    float:left;
    width:700px;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:0 5px 5px 5px;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    display:none;
    clear:left;
    top:-1px;
    box-shadow:0 15px 10px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.tabcontent p {
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    margin:0;
    font:normal 12px/20px arial, sans-serif;
    color:#333;
}
.tabcontent h4 {
    padding:0 0 10px 0;
    margin:0;
    font:bold 14px/25px arial, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
}
.tabcontent img {
    border:1px solid #444;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;
    box-shadow:0 15px 10px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

/* change the tab to selected style */
ul.tabs li a.default, #tab1:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.default, #tab2:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.tab2, #tab3:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.tab3, #tab4:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.tab4, #tab5:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.tab5 {
background-color:#fff;
border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
color:#000;
}

/* show the tab content */
div.default, #tab1:target ~ .tabbedPages div.default, #tab2:target ~ .tabbedPages div#view2, #tab3:target ~ .tabbedPages div#view3, #tab4:target ~ .tabbedPages div#view4, #tab5:target ~ .tabbedPages div#view5 {
display:block;
}

/* reset the unclicked tabs to default */
#tab2:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.default, #tab3:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.default, #tab4:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.default, #tab5:target ~ .tabbedPages .tabs li a.default {
background-color:#69c;
border:1px solid #888;
color:#fff;
}

/* hide the default tab when selecting other tabs*/
#tab2:target ~ .tabbedPages div.default, #tab3:target ~ .tabbedPages div.default, #tab4:target ~ .tabbedPages div.default, #tab5:target ~ .tabbedPages div.default {
display:none;
}
.clear {
    clear:left;
}
}
.hiddenTargetTwo {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
}
.tabbedPagesTwo {
    position:relative;
    margin:50px 0;
    display:block;
}
ul.tabsTwo {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}
ul.tabsTwo li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:2px;
}
ul.tabsTwo li a {
    display:block;
    font:normal 12px/30px arial, sans-serif;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    background:#69c;
    padding:0 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)), color-stop(0.5, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)));
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
    background-image:linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
}
.tabcontentTwo {
    float:left;
    width:700px;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:0 5px 5px 5px;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    display:none;
    clear:left;
    top:-1px;
    box-shadow:0 15px 10px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.tabcontentTwo p {
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    margin:0;
    font:normal 12px/20px arial, sans-serif;
    color:#333;
}
.tabcontentTwo h4 {
    padding:0 0 10px 0;
    margin:0;
    font:bold 14px/25px arial, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
}
.tabcontentTwo img {
    border:1px solid #444;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;
    box-shadow:0 15px 10px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

/* change the tab to selected style */
ul.tabsTwo li a.default, #tab6:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo .tabsTwo li a.tab6, #tab7:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo .tabsTwo li a.tab7, #tab8:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo .tabsTwo li a.tab8, #tab9:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo .tabsTwo li a.tab9, #tab10:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo .tabsTwo li a.tab10 {
background-color:#fff;
border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
color:#000;
}

/* show the tab content */
div.default, #tab6:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo div#view6, #tab7:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo div#view7, #tab8:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo div#view8, #tab9:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo div#view9, #tab10:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo div#view10 {
display:block;
}

/* reset the unclicked tabs to default */
#tab6:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo .tabsTwo li a.default, #tab7:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo .tabsTwo li a.default, #tab8:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo .tabsTwo li a.default,, #tab9:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo .tabsTwo li a.default, #tab10:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo .tabsTwo li a.default {
background-color:#69c;
border:1px solid #888;
color:#fff;
}

/* hide the default tab when selecting other tabs*/
#tab6:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo div.default, #tab7:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo div.default, #tab8:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo div.default, #tab9:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo div.default, #tab10:target ~ .tabbedPagesTwo div.default {
display:none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<b id="tab1" class="hiddenTarget"></b>
<b id="tab2" class="hiddenTarget"></b>
<b id="tab3" class="hiddenTarget"></b>
<b id="tab4" class="hiddenTarget"></b>
<b id="tab5" class="hiddenTarget"></b>
<div class="tabbedPages">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1" class="default tab1 tabpages">Tab One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" class="tab2 tabpages">Tab Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3" class="tab3 tabpages">Tab Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4" class="tab4 tabpages">Tab Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5" class="tab5 tabpages">Tab Five</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="view1" class="tabcontent default">
        <h4>Tab 'persist'</h4>
        <p>The most recently clicked tab will be remembered and stay open even if you click elsewhere on the page or if the page is reloaded.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view2" class="tabcontent">
        <h4>Multiple Tabs</h4>
        <p>You can have multiple tabs on the same page, with only one copy of the CSS (javascript is not required).</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view3" class="tabcontent">
        <h4>Tab Action from elsewhere on the same page.</h4>
        <p>You can also open a tab using links elsewhere on the same page.</p>
        <p>If you click this <a href="#tab1" class="tabpages">LINK</a> you will open 'Tab One' content, and if you click the link beneath this Tab Content you will open 'Tab #2' content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view4" class="tabcontent">
        <h4>Opened by a link from another page</h4>
        <p>Link from another page can select a tab on the target page when loaded.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view5" class="tabcontent">
        <h4>No restrictions on tab content</h4>
        <img src="pollensa.jpg" alt=" Polenca - Mallorca" />
        <p>Port de Pollença (Catalan pronunciation: [ˈpɔrd də poˈʎɛnsə]) (Puerto Pollensa in Castilian Spanish) is a small town in north-eastern Mallorca, Spain, situated on the Bay of Pollença. It is located about six kilometres east of the inland town of Pollença and two kilometres southeast of Cala Sant Vicenç.</p>
        <p>From <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_de_Pollen%C3%A7a">Wikipedia</a>, the free encyclopedia.</p>
        <br />
        <p>Photograph &copy stu nicholls</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<b id="tab6" class="hiddenTargetTwo"></b>
<b id="tab7" class="hiddenTargetTwo"></b>
<b id="tab8" class="hiddenTargetTwo"></b>
<b id="tab9" class="hiddenTargetTwo"></b>
<b id="tab10" class="hiddenTargetTwo"></b>
<div class="tabbedPagesTwo">
    <ul class="tabsTwo">
        <li><a href="#tab6" class="default tab6 tabpagesTwo">Tab Six</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab7" class="tab7 tabpagesTwo">Tab Seven</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab8" class="tab8 tabpagesTwo">Tab Eight</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab9" class="tab9 tabpagesTwo">Tab Nine</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab10" class="tab10 tabpagesTwo">Tab Ten</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="view6" class="tabcontentTwo default">
        <h4>Tab 'persist'</h4>
        <p>The most recently clicked tab will be remembered and stay open even if you click elsewhere on the page or if the page is reloaded.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view7" class="tabcontentTwo">
        <h4>Multiple Tabs</h4>
        <p>You can have multiple tabs on the same page, with only one copy of the CSS (javascript is not required).</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view8" class="tabcontentTwo">
        <h4>Tab Action from elsewhere on the same page.</h4>
        <p>You can also open a tab using links elsewhere on the same page.</p>
        <p>If you click this <a href="#tab1" class="tabpages">LINK</a> you will open 'Tab One' content, and if you click the link beneath this Tab Content you will open 'Tab #2' content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view9" class="tabcontentTwo">
        <h4>Opened by a link from another page</h4>
        <p>Link from another page can select a tab on the target page when loaded.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="view10" class="tabcontentTwo">
        <h4>No restrict ions on tab content</h4>
        <img src="pollensa.jpg" alt=" Polenca - Mallorca" />
        <p>Port de Pollença (Catalan pronunciation: [ˈpɔrd də poˈʎɛnsə]) (Puerto Pollensa in Castilian Spanish) is a small town in north-eastern Mallorca, Spain, situated on the Bay of Pollença. It is located about six kilometres east of the inland town of Pollença and two kilometres southeast of Cala Sant Vicenç.</p>
        <p>From <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_de_Pollen%C3%A7a">Wikipedia</a>, the free encyclopedia.</p>
        <br />
        <p>Photograph &copy stu nicholls</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you were having was because both sets of CSS tabs had the same IDs.  Copy/pasting the CSS and changing the IDs works but in the future you should try not to do that. A better way would be to assign each of the elements a "class" in addition to their ID. This would allow you to reuse the CSS you already had.  You would then use javascript to manipulate them based on their ID.

Hope this helps!
Bobby

Comment: Thank you @bobby603 I am not using javascript at all though right now. It is just CSS and HTML.